# Pivot/Unpivot and Ranking paired data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

in a table where each row has 9 matched pairs is it possible to use Pivot to produce columns, so for example the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID,
    HOME_APPDTE1,
    HOMENUMBER1,
    HOME_APPDTE2,   
    HOMENUMBER2, 
    HOME_APPDTE3,  
    HOMENUMBER3,  
    WORK_APPDTE1,   
    WORKNUMBER2,
    WORK_APPDTE2,
    WORKNUMBER3,
    WORK_APPDTE3,
    WORKNUMBER1,
    MOBILE_APPDTE1,
    MOBILENUMBER1,
    MOBILE_APPDTE2,
    MOBILENUMBER2,
    MOBILE_APPDTE3, 
    MOBILENUMBER3
FROM 
    Telephone_Numbers
```

returns

```
ID  HOME_APPDTE1    HOMENUMBER1 HOME_APPDTE2    HOMENUMBER2 HOME_APPDTE3    HOMENUMBER3 WORK_APPDTE1    WORKNUMBER2 WORK_APPDTE2    WORKNUMBER3 WORK_APPDTE3    WORKNUMBER1 MOBILE_APPDTE1  MOBILENUMBER1   MOBILE_APPDTE2  MOBILENUMBER2   MOBILE_APPDTE3  MOBILENUMBER3
23  2016-11-25  111111111   2015-06-22  222222222   2015-02-22  333333333   2017-01-25  444444444   2016-02-12  555555555   2015-06-13  666666666   2017-05-18  777777777   2016-12-23  888888888   2016-01-11  999999999
```

but I am after

```
ID  Type    Date_Changed    Tel_Number  Rank
23  Home    2016-11-25  111111111   1
23  Home    2015-06-22  222222222   2
23  Home    2015-02-22  333333333   3
23  Work    2017-01-25  444444444   1
23  Work    2016-02-12  555555555   2
23  Work    2015-06-13  666666666   3
23  Mobile  2017-05-18  777777777   1
23  Mobile  2016-12-23  888888888   2
23  Mobile  2016-01-11  999999999   3
```

Many thanks in advance of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need dynamic, yet another option is using a **CROSS APPLY**.

Also, assuming you didn't need a dynamic solution.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('Home'  ,HOME_APPDTE1  ,HOMENUMBER1  ,1)
                     ,('Home'  ,HOME_APPDTE2  ,HOMENUMBER2  ,2)
                     ,('Home'  ,HOME_APPDTE3  ,HOMENUMBER3  ,3)
                     ,('Work'  ,WORK_APPDTE1  ,WORKNUMBER1  ,1)
                     ,('Work'  ,WORK_APPDTE2  ,WORKNUMBER2  ,2)
                     ,('Work'  ,WORK_APPDTE3  ,WORKNUMBER2  ,3)
                     ,('Mobile',MOBILE_APPDTE1,MOBILENUMBER1,1)
                     ,('Mobile',MOBILE_APPDTE2,MOBILENUMBER2,2)
                     ,('Mobile',MOBILE_APPDTE3,MOBILENUMBER3,3)
             ) B ([Type],[DateChanged],[Tel_Number],[Rank])
```

Comment: Thanks @John this formed the basis for my answer.

Comment: @MarkHedley Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

This is a **really bad design**... I hope you are needing this to sort this out...

**As a general rule:**
Whenever you want to create columns with an index to its name (like `Date1`, `Date2`) this is a clear sign that you need a related side table!

You might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT,HOME_APPDTE1 DATE,HOMENUMBER1 VARCHAR(100)
                            ,HOME_APPDTE2 DATE,HOMENUMBER2 VARCHAR(100)
                            ,HOME_APPDTE3 DATE,HOMENUMBER3 VARCHAR(100)
                            ,WORK_APPDTE1 DATE,WORKNUMBER1 VARCHAR(100) 
                            ,WORK_APPDTE2 DATE,WORKNUMBER2 VARCHAR(100));

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (23,'2014-11-25','111111111'
    ,'2011-05-03','222222222'
    ,'2015-12-12','333333333'
    ,'2014-04-02','444444444'
    ,'2014-02-24','555555555');

WITH Normalized AS
(
              SELECT ID,'Home' AS [Type],HOME_APPDTE1 AS DateChanged,HOMENUMBER1 AS Tel_Number,1 AS [Rank] FROM @mockup
    UNION ALL SELECT ID,'Home',HOME_APPDTE2,HOMENUMBER2,2 FROM @mockup
    UNION ALL SELECT ID,'Home',HOME_APPDTE3,HOMENUMBER3,3 FROM @mockup
    UNION ALL SELECT ID,'Work',WORK_APPDTE1,WORKNUMBER1,1 FROM @mockup
    UNION ALL SELECT ID,'Work',WORK_APPDTE2,WORKNUMBER2,2 FROM @mockup
)
SELECT *
FROM Normalized
ORDER BY ID,[Type],[Rank];
```

### What you should do:

The ID in your table `Telephone_Numbers` is assumeable a person's ID. So there's a persons table probably. Now you need something like this:

- a `phone_type` catalog
- a `phone_number` table, where you need

  - `PhoneID (PK), OwnerID (FK), PhoneTypeID (FK), ChangeDate and Number`. You might need a `Rank` column, if the rank is not taken from the change date's order...

In fact, the target structure you are trying to achieve is roughly the structure how you should store your data actually...

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Shnugo and I agree "the target structure you are trying to achieve is roughly the structure how you should store your data actually" but unfortunately the source data is from a third party with which we have no influence to change the structure.

Comment: @MarkHedley, okay, that's bad luck... Hope my answer will help you to sort this out...